# Using basename to strip file extension and search for files with the same name

Tags: shell-script, find, filenames

Basically, I have a folder `/test/` that has a number of files of type `.doc` and `.pdf`. Some of the files have a `.pdf` and a `.doc` version, such as `test.doc` and `test.pdf` while others only have one version.

What I'm trying to do is find occurrences where there is a `.doc` and delete the corresponding `.pdf` using a script.

I've been tinkering with this line of code:

```
find /test/ -name "*.doc" - exec basename {} .doc \; -exec rm {}.pdf \;
```

However this returns the error that it cannot find files named `example.doc.pdf` instead of deleting the appropriately named `.pdf` from the find command. The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because there are `.pdf` files which don't have a matching `.doc` file which I do not wish to delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find /test/ -name "*.doc" -exec sh -c 'a="$1"; rm "${a%.doc}.pdf"' find-sh {} \;
```

It will search for `.doc` files in the directory `/test/`. For each found file a shell `sh` is called with the file as argument. `${a%.doc}.pdf` replaces the file extension `.doc` with `.pdf` and `rm` removes it, if the file exists.

Comment: What does the `find-sh` part do?  I'm tracking with everything but that part and how `$1` in the `sh` call ends up holding the filename.

Comment: @Wildcard `$1` is the first argument given to the script by `{}` at the end which holds the filename. This is stored in a variable `$a` to do variable substitution. `find-sh` is just the name I gave the script. It can be anything.

Comment: I see...am I correct in my understanding that you could omit `find-sh` and change the `$1` to `$0` and it would still work?

Comment: @Wildcard No, `$0` is the filename of the current script, not an argument.

Comment: From `man sh`:
      -c string If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from
                 string.  If there are arguments after the  string,  they  are
                 assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Comment: I tested this command; it turns out it does work: `find . -name "*.doc" -exec sh -c 'a="$0"; rm "${a%.doc}.pdf"' {} \;`  This is because of the way `sh -c` assigns positional parameters, but I could see that using `$1` might be more clear.  Except that it makes the reader wonder where this `find-sh` is that is being mentioned, if he's unfamiliar with `sh -c`.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard As I have written `$0` is for the inline script name which is used for instance when displaying error messages. In the above example it contains `find-sh`. It becomes relevant when you call `find` with `-exec sh -c '...' find-sh {} +` (notice the `+`), because then `"$@"` contains the list of the arguments $1, $2, ..., without `$0`. So, in the above example it might work with `$0`, but keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following script as `rm_dub.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

rm_dub() {
    dir=$(dirname -- "$1")
    base=$(basename -- "$1" "$2")

    rm -- "$dir/$base$3"
}

rm_dub "$@"
```

and uses it with

```
find /test/ -name "*.doc" -exec sh rm_dub.sh {} .doc .pdf \;
```

Comment: I like the script but where does the actual deleting occur?

Comment: @Wildcard added the `rm`